# Weaving production aspect into test class with Gradle AspectJ

Tags: java, groovy, gradle, aspectj

I am using the Gradle AspectJ plugin to weave some production aspect into test Java code. I would have expected this to work out of the box with the plugin, but apparently that's not the case as demoed here:
https://github.com/sedubois/gradle-aspectj-poc/tree/dc44f529831a485fcff8f4889dba8098784dddb4

The weaving of `UnsupportedOperationAspect` into `MainSevice` (both under `src/main/java`) works, but the weaving of this same aspect into `TestService` (under `src/test/java`) doesn't.

I am new to Groovy, Gradle and AspectJ and didn't figure out if I should add some `testAspectpath` configuration or similar?

EDIT1: seems unrelated, but iajc gives a warning:

`...
:compileTestAspect
[ant:iajc] [warning] incorrect classpath: [...]\gradle-aspectj-poc\build\resources\main
...`

EDIT2: I naively added this code to the Gradle dependencies:

```
ajInpath fileTree(dir: "src/test/java")
aspectpath fileTree(dir: "src/test/java")
testAjInpath fileTree(dir: "src/test/java")
testAspectpath fileTree(dir: "src/test/java")
```

It doesn't help, the first test works and the second one fails as usual, with these new messages:

`...
:compileAspect
[ant:iajc] [warning] build config error: skipping missing, empty or corrupt aspectpath entry: [...]\gradle-aspectj-poc\src\test\java\com\hello\aop\TestService.java
[ant:iajc] [warning] build config error: skipping missing, empty or corrupt inpath entry: [...]\gradle-aspectj-poc\src\test\java\com\hello\aop\TestService.java
...
:compileTestAspect
[ant:iajc] [warning] build config error: skipping missing, empty or corrupt aspectpath entry: [...]\gradle-aspectj-poc\src\test\java\com\hello\aop\TestService.java
[ant:iajc] [warning] build config error: skipping missing, empty or corrupt inpath entry: [...]\gradle-aspectj-poc\src\test\java\com\hello\aop\TestService.java
[ant:iajc] [warning] incorrect classpath: [...]\gradle-aspectj-poc\build\resources\main
...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default the plugin does not weave the main aspects in the test classes - we simply never made a configuration option for it. You can do this yourself using the following line:

```
testAspectpath sourceSets.main.output
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on where exactly this goes?  Ta!

Comment: In your dependencies section, see the docs at https://github.com/eveoh/gradle-aspectj

Comment: Cool thanks, that works.  Not sure what I did before to make me think it didn't.  Unfortunately (I'm very new to all this), it is not helping me weave in integrationTests.

Comment: MikeN, you seem to be a committer to gradle-aspectj and so must have a grater understanding of gradle and this plugin in particular.  I asked a question about the plugin at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38680678/why-gradle-aspectj-doesnt-pick-up-integrationtest-sourceset - can you have a look?

Answer (score 0):

There is no expression matching `TestService#serviceMethod()`.

In order to make your testcase work you need to advice your service method and (very important) the aspect must be located in the `src/test/` package. Otherwise the compiler would not weave it in.

```
// located in `src/test/java` 

package com.hello.aop;

@Aspect
class UnsupportedOperationAspect {

    @Before("execution(void com.hello.aop.TestService.serviceMethod(..))")
    public void throwUnsupportedOperationOnMethod1() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
}
```

Just a sidenote as i do not know what you are trying to achieve by advising test-classes (that are components specifically for test cases only): keep your tests as simple as possible.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to rename the pointcut when refactoring the code for publishing, I fixed it and updated the link. But as you said, why "the compiler would not weave" into test classes? This is what I'm trying to fix. The aim of my test is to *test* the *production* aspect in isolation.

Comment: So I want to use the production `AopConfig` on the `TestService` test class, not to mix the test with other production code but to isolate it to the minimal code required to test just that aspect.